# Obfuscation when compiling?

Tags: c#

Are there methods to obfuscate during/after compile that are automated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different tools and third party offerings. [DotFuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) is probably the best known of them.

[Here](http://howtoselectguides.com/dotnet/obfuscators/1st) is a handy guide to selecting an obfuscation tool.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run some sort of obfuscator program.  Here is a list of some for .Net: http://www.csharp411.com/net-obfuscators/